# Java Library for editing doc attributes

Tags: java, metadata

I want to write a java program for editing a doc file's metadata author, title, subject etc.
please tell me a library to do so...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents](http://poi.apache.org/)

> Apache POI provides text extraction for all the supported file
>   formats. In addition, it provides access to the metadata associated
>   with a given file, such as title and author.

Take a look at [getDocSummaryInformation()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIOLE2TextExtractor.html#getDocSummaryInformation%28%29) it returns,

> Returns the document information metadata for the document

and also take a look at this [nice example](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/6/Working-with-Office-Metadata).(see its comment section)